# Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers

Tags: java

The code doesn't pass all the tests, only passes 5 tests.
One of the failed test cases

Wrong Answer

**Input (stdin)**

`793810624 895642170 685903712 623789054 468592370`

**Expected Output**

`2572095760 2999145560`

```java
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        //initialize array
        int arr[]=new int[5];
        int sum=0;

        //array elements
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            sum+=arr[i];           
        }
    
        //Sorting the array and storing the minimum and maximum values
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int min=arr[4];
        int max=arr[0];
        int minSum = sum-min;
        int maxSum = sum-max;
        System.out.println(minSum+" "+maxSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maximal `int` value is 2147483647.

Answer (score 2):

Use `long` instead of `int`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // initialize array

    long arr[] = new long[5];
    long sum = 0;
    // array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
      sum += arr[i];
    }

    // Sorting the array and storing the minimum and maximum values

    Arrays.sort(arr);
    long min = arr[4];
    long max = arr[0];
    long minSum = sum - min;
    long maxSum = sum - max;
    System.out.println(minSum + " " + maxSum);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `long` and not `Long`

Answer (score 0):

U reaching the max value of int. U should convert these values to long

```
long sum=0;
long minSum = sum-min;
long maxSum = sum-max;
```

After converting these values my output was

```
2572095760 2999145560
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in C#

```
public static void miniMaxSum(List<int> arr)
{   
        long[] newArr = new long[arr.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            long aux = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Count; j++)
            {
                aux = (i != j) ? aux += arr[j] : aux;
            }
            newArr[i] = aux;  
        }
        Console.WriteLine(newArr.Min() + " " + newArr.Max());
}
```